# Is it possible to start a Java Runtime Image with prunsrv using jvm mode?

Tags: java-9, java-module, jlink, apache-commons-daemon, prunsrv

Background: Since Java 9 it is possible to create [custom runtime images](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220) (JRE+program) using [jlink](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/282).

It is possible to install Java programs as Windows service using *prunsrv.exe* (part of [Apache Commons Daemon](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/)).

*prunsrv* can be used in three start modes: *java*, *jvm* and *exe*.

I managed to start a custom runtime image using the *exe* mode and a traditional Java program (classpath + normal JDK) using *jvm* mode, but I was not able to use the *jvm* mode (which doesn't start a new process) with the image.

*prunsrv* has a "*JvmOptions9*" parameter, which could be a hint that this scenario may be supported, but I am not sure.

Comment: You should elaborate on “but I was not able to use the jvm mode … with the image”, i.e. what have you tried, what happened then, error messages, unintended behavior, etc.

Comment: I found it difficult to debug and there seems to be little log output. Before spending more time, I would like to know if it should work somehow or if is plainly not (yet) possible.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue at first, but managed to solve it. While this is an old issue it was the first I found when I searched, so I will provide my answer for others.

I could install the service without problems, but when I tried to start it in jvm mode it would fail and complain that "%1 is not a valid Win32 application". The keyword here is Win32.

There are two versions of the prunsrv executable: one in the installation directory and one in the amd64 subdirectory. The version in the installation directory only supports 32 bit, while the one in amd64 is for 64 bit code. The prunsrv and the Java version must both be 32 bit or 64 bit; I was trying to start a 64 bit Java VM from a 32 bit prunsrv service.

In other words, make sure that the correct version of prunsrv for the intended Java VM is used. With that I can run a modular Java 9 (or actually 12) application with a stripped down runtime image without problems.